# Use case for RuntimeException from package Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I was writing some code and was going to throw a `RuntimeException` as a default for something, when I noticed that there are two options for `RuntimeException` - one from `java.lang` and one from `kotlin`:
[image]

Inside the kotlin version of this, there's an entire list of other methods which work the same way :

[image]

So, from my understanding of this, the one from package `kotlin` is simply an alias for the java equivalent (correct me if I'm wrong) which leads me to the question :

what is the point of having this alias file and when should you use it over the "standard" java equivalent ? Does this simply save a few imports ?

Comment: I think there's no real use case in this exception, it's only a parent for some Kotlin-specific exceptions, like `UninitializedPropertyAccessException`

Comment: I think alias were created in case of provide some fluent API like Kotlin DSL in nearer future. It's like following abstract factory pattern to provide APIs/SDK with minimal or none change logs if we got to higher versions of library.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using the JDK, these map to JDK classes. When using Kotlin for Javascript, they would map to a specific implementation in the Kotlin Javascript library. Documentation about `actual` and `expect` [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/platform-specific-declarations.html).

To answer your question, if there's a chance of you porting your code to also work on another platform, always use the `kotlin.` variant. Otherwise, it doesn't matter.

Comment: learn something new every day, thanks for your answer, this was pretty cool

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion **typealias** is strong feature provided by Kotlin language.

*Why?* Because it gives ability to extend code to multiple domains like extension to provide interoperability between any other languages and Kotlin.

It also becomes helpful when providing *APIs or SDK* with semantic versioning without worrying much about changes affecting on lower versions of APIs.

One good example would be [Collections](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/collections-overview.html) derived from Java to Kotlin language with some additional & powerful methods as typealias *(Literally it saves lot of development time and efforts)*.

Another good example would be **multiplatform programming** support by Kotlin language that helps you create APIs with **actual** and **expect** keywords implementation.

So long story short, I prefer using `RuntimeException` from Kotlin package to extend support amongst variety of Kotlin versions *(You can see newly added classes starting from version 1.3, but doesn't affect existing API)*.