# Kotlin: isNullOrEmpty vs TextUtils.isEmpty

Tags: android, kotlin, textutils

In Kotlin (Android project), which is preferable to use ?

`isNullOrEmpty` or `TextUtils.isEmpty` and why

I believe they do the exact thing and are "null" safe, right ?

Comment: They both check for `null` and a length of `0`, so they just do the same... I would then stick to Kotlin and use `CharSequence.isNullOrEmpty`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based off of my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58186339/use-case-for-runtimeexception-from-package-kotlin)

If your project will be ported to other frameworks, making use of `isNullOrEmpty` will probably result in a safer experience, because it's based on Kotlin (specifically `package kotlin.text`) and not on `package android.text;`

Why is this safer ?

Well, the implementation of `isNullOrEmpty` might change depending on the platform but it will be available to use and is part of Kotlin, compared to `TextUtils.isEmpty` being only for android.

Comment: What other platform other than Android was OP referring to?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky with Kotlin Native being a thing (no expert on this) i believe that you can write Kotlin code which could be converted to ios or to android, if that answers your comment ?

Comment: Interesting, haven't heard of anybody developing Kotlin Native in production at this point.

Comment: me neither @IgorGanapolsky, this question was just related to something i found myself while coding normal android :)

Answer (score 3):

I would say `isNullOrEmpty` is slightly preferable, because it's a language's feature. `TextUtils.isEmpty` is a library function, external to Kotlin.

Answer (score 1):

For string.isEmpty(), a null string value will throw a NullPointerException
Incase of isNullOrEmpty it will check first value is null or not and it will proceed for the empty check. isNullOrEmpty is preferable

Comment: What about `TextUtils.isEmpty`, which was mentioned in the question? The question did not mention `String.isEmpty`

Comment: Both will be the same, The only difference is we are taking the advantage of kotlin extensions here in kotlin

Answer (score 1):

The code for `TextUtils.isEmpty`:

```
public static boolean isEmpty(@Nullable CharSequence str) {
        return str == null || str.length() == 0;
    }
```

The code for `isNullOrEmpty`:

```
public inline fun CharSequence?.isNullOrEmpty(): Boolean {
    contract {
        returns(false) implies (this@isNullOrEmpty != null)
    }

    return this == null || this.length == 0
}
```

Witch is basically the same, the inline function also has a contract that will tell the compiler to return false if the value is not null, not sure what the actual usage is, maybe it's an optimization.

Answer (score 1):

Yes , the only difference is `NullPointerException`.

In `isNullOrEmpty` first it will check string is null or not .if it is not null then it will check it is check string is empty or not . If any of the condition will true then method will return true.

In  `TextUtils.isEmpty` it check `string` is empty or not .If `string` is null then it will throw `NullPointerException` and your app will crash .

Comment: That is not true.
public static boolean isEmpty(@Nullable CharSequence str) {
        return str == null || str.length() == 0;
    }

Answer (score 1):

`TextUtils.isEmpty` is basically the **same** thing with `isNullOrEmpty()`. Yet, there are differences in terms of availability and compilation:

1) `TextUtils.isEmpty` is available from the `android.text` package, available with Android SDK, and `isNullOrEmpty()` requires Koltin dependency (`kotlin.text` package).

2) Another difference is that `isNullOrEmpty()` is an `inline` extension function and it is compiled differently, perhaps with a slight performance boost.

> Apart from these, there is another useful inline function
>   `isNullOrBlank()`. It also returns true if the String contains **only
>   white spaces**.

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin isNullOrEmpty is preferable. TextUtils.isEmpty is specific to Java. 
Both returns boolean if string is empty or null.

Comment: Are there exceptions thrown?